# Uploading videos on YouTube with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, video, youtube, uploading

I am relatively new to Ruby on Rails and I want to make all users upload videos on my YouTube account. To do so I have to use oauth to send my gmail and gmail password and to get the access token and pass it to the user who is currently logged in my website. Sadly, I don't know how to do that and any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Show what you have done. This is not a coding service.

Comment: As it stands your question is too broad and off topic ... please review [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and consider providing a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I understand your remark. I just ask how to send my gmail and password through oauth, the rest is done.